# DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation cannot be used to animate property RenderTransform 'cause it is of incompatible type Transform

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am getting this exception in my WPF Application when using `MetroContentControl` of `MahApps.Metro`.

```
'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'RenderTransform' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform'.
```

My View is not rendered in design mode. But works great on Build.

Can anyone suggest me, what are the possible solution for this exception.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you cannot use double animation simply because the `RenderTransform` is not of type `double`. Have a look at `PropertyAnimation` instead and supply it with a new whole `Transform` object.